# How to write class/function that returns large amount of html

Tags: php, return-value, string-formatting

I'm used to using includes with large chunks of html outside of the php code, but I'm trying to move to classes or functions because they have increased flexibility and potential for design patterns etc.

I need a function right now that will return a large amount of html, mixed in with some php variables, but I'm looking for away to keep the code outside of the `<?php` declaration so that it will be formatted like proper html and have code hinting, rather than being a gigantic string.

If it's possible, how would I go about formatting/writing that?

Comment: Do you want a templating engine?

Comment: you may find useful [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) syntax.

Comment: You can name your files with `.phtml` extension. Most web servers handle it as *PHP w/ Embedded HTML*. Editors and IDE do that too. `.php` also works, but I prefer `.phtml` because it makes it clear that the file is a template file and not a class, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `include('somefile.html');`.

**include** works with vanilla HTML too.

If you need to have it "mixed in with some php variables", just add those when you need them. Remember: PHP, by its very nature, is a templating language.

For example:

**outerHTML.php:**

```
<?php function generateCode($username) { ?>

    <h1>Welcome back, <?php echo $username; ?></h1>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>

<?php } ?>
```

**main.php:**

```
<?php

// some PHP code

include('outerHTML.php');

generateCode('John');

// some more PHP code

?>
```

Comment: I want the `outerHTML.php` output to be within a function that can have parameters

Comment: @Damon: Like I said, you can mix PHP with HTML freely. Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this...

```
function getPage() {
    ob_start();
    include("file_with_html.php");
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    return $content;
}
```

Of course, you can add other functionality as needed.  But, the advantage here is that you're using output buffering.  Without this, the data is sent to the user right away.  But, using the `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`, you can return it and work with it some more.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use output buffering within your classes. See comments at http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php